# Work with 2d array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I create 2d array with random number

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function matrixArray(rows, columns) {
          var min = 0;
          var max = 10;
          var arr = new Array();
          for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
              arr[i] = new Array();
              for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                  arr[i][j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
              }
          }
          return arr;
      }
</script>
```

Now i wont write function that create table with delete button in all rows. And function that delete row from array and redraw the table. Try like this, but not working

```
<script>
        function createtab (arr)
        {
            var inpts = [], t = document.createElement('TABLE');
            t.cellSpacing = 0, t.cellPadding = 5, t.border = 1;
            for (var j = 0, J = arr.length; j < J; j++) {
                var ro = t.insertRow(-1),
           ce = ro.insertCell(-1),
           inpt = document.createElement('INPUT');
                inpt.type = 'button', inpt.value = 'Delete', inpt.onclick = 'rowdel(arr,'+j+')';
                inpts.unshift(ce.appendChild(inpt));
                for (var k = 0, K = arr[j].length; k < K; k++) { var ce = ro.insertCell(-1); ce.innerHTML = arr[j][k] }
            }

           var obj = document.getElementById('forTable').appendChild(t);           
        }
</script>
```

delete row on button click

```
<script>
    function rowdel(arr, i) {
        arr.splice(i, 1);
        createtab(arr);
     }
</script>
```

html body

```
<body>
<div id="forTable"></div>  
 <script>
     var arr = matrixArray(6, 7);
     createtab(arr);
 </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var arr = matrixArray(6, 7);
        createtab(arr);
    });

    function matrixArray(rows, columns) {
        var min = 0;
        var max = 10;
        var arr = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            arr[i] = new Array();
            for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }

    function createtab (arr)
    {
        var inpts = [], t = document.createElement('TABLE');
        t.cellSpacing = 0, t.cellPadding = 5, t.border = 1;
        for (var j = 0, J = arr.length; j < J; j++) {
            var ro = t.insertRow(-1),
       ce = ro.insertCell(-1),
       inpt = document.createElement('INPUT');
            inpt.type = 'button', inpt.value = 'Delete',inpt.attributes['id']=j, inpt.onclick =function() { rowdel(arr,this)};
            inpts.unshift(ce.appendChild(inpt));
            for (var k = 0, K = arr[j].length; k < K; k++) { var ce = ro.insertCell(-1); ce.innerHTML = arr[j][k];
    //alert(j);
             }
        }

       var obj = document.getElementById('forTable').appendChild(t);           
    }

  function rowdel(arr,input) {
     var i = input.attributes['id'];
        arr.splice(i, 1);
        $('#forTable').empty();
    createtab(arr);
 }


    </script>

    <body>
    <div id="forTable"></div>  

    </body>
```

Comment: with ajax - empty page. inpt.attributes['id']=j not supported (when i delete it from previous variant (without ajax)) table created, but on button click new table added to previous, how to redraw table after button click?

Comment: but i'm getting every thing.

Comment: save your code as htm and run on chrome - empty page

Comment: then use .php and see.

Comment: put entire code in yourfilename.htm,.html,.php and browse that page.

Comment: i copy your code (see above) to htm - run - empty page

Comment: in your code - body empty, where you call function that create array and table?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ }); will do that part it means on page ready.

Comment: and how to redraw page after button click (i need only one table on the page)? now new table added to previuos

Comment: change rowdel to function rowdel(arr,input) {
     var i = input.attributes['id'];
        arr.splice(i, 1);
        $('#forTable').empty();
    createtab(arr);
 }

Comment: Thks, and without ajax ? and in ie8 not supportet input.attributes['id'], how to fix it? (this page will be us on ie8 without internet)

Comment: in that case you can use only inpt.id=j, instead of input.attributes['id'],

Comment: i have used $(document).ready thing and your part also the way you used <body>
<div id="forTable"></div>  
<script>

    var arr = matrixArray(6, 7);
    createtab(arr);
</script>
</body> both are working.

Comment: i about redraw table -  $('#forTable').empty();

Comment: use this : $('#forTable').html(" ");

Comment: i cant use ajax in this page

Comment: i use document.getElementById("forTable").innerHTML = ""; - it works, maybe it be helpful for someone

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to redraw the table .

```
inpt.onclick = 'rowdel(arr,'+j+',this)';

function rowdel(arr, i, input) {
    arr.splice(i, 1);
    var row = input.parentNode.parentNode;
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
 }
```

UPDATE: onclick requires a function

```
inpt.attributes['id']=j;
inpt.onclick = function () {
                    rowdel(this);
};

function rowdel(input) {
    var i = input.attributes['id'];
    arr.splice(i, 1);
    var row = input.parentNode.parentNode;
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}
```

Comment: Thks, but i need 3 function - create array , create table with array and buttons, function that delete row and redraw table (by task)

Comment: updated the answer, and if this is a school task or something i think you are misunderstanding the `redraw table` part

Comment: update When i run it i dont see table in browser, i think all rows will be deliting. And splice is not work, i use button '<input type="button" value="view an array" onclick="alert (arr.join ('\n'))">' to show array value

Comment: inpt.attributes['id']=j not supportet

Comment: sorry in ie 8 it nor supported, i write for this browser

Comment: @e1s you should use libraries like `jquery` to make sure you have cross browser support

Answer (score 0):

you can define you del function such like that.

```
var  dele = function rowdel(arr, i) {
        return function(){
          arr.splice(i, 1);
          createtab(arr);
        }

     }
```

and use it as like closures as .

```
inpt.type = 'button', inpt.value = 'Delete', inpt.onclick = dele(arr, j);
```

Comment: hope this will be work for you , for more detail 

http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/closures/